# Create Permanent Redirect for old URL not working - Magento 2

Tags: url-rewrite, url-key

I have update product URL-key but still, the old URL is working. New URL is not working.

Solution applied: ACSD-45168  patch applied. It generates the rewrites, but with the old url, not the new url-key.

This happens for products that have url_key attributes overridden.

[image]

Create Permanent Redirect for old URL is checked. Still its not creating the redirects.

Please help.

Thank You.